# Laravel Spark Token

Tags: laravel-spark

In the installations doc, before installing or creating new Spark project, there's a need to register API token.

```
spark register token-value
```

I would like to know what is the purpose of registering the token and it is possible to change or update the token after I completely installed my Spark project.

It is necessary to register token again when moving my project to a different machine?

Thanks!

Comment: It's basically the key that confirms you own Spark, and then allows you to pull the repo. Without a key you can't install Spark :)

Comment: Thanks! It is necessary for me to set the token in the production server also? and can I use single token to create multiple Spark projects?

Comment: One license per live project, you need it for production yeah, otherwise it won't work. You can use the same key on unlimited local developments, but as soon as one goes live that key is consumed, you'd need another license etc.